# Re-installing GRUB to external boot drive

Tags: grub2, system-installation, uefi

I am trying to make a full installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on an external drive and make the installation bootable on my Macbook Air (early 2014) without using rEFInd.

I was following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@mmiglier/ubuntu-installation-on-usb-stick-with-pure-efi-boot-mac-compatible-469ad33645c9

Everything went smoothly until trying to install GRUB back.

```
$ sudo grub-install --target x86_64-efi --boot-directory=/boot
--efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id="$(lsb_release -ds)"
```

returned something like "/boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition".

I had to go to bed (it was late), so I had to shut down the computer before I managed to make the system bootable.

1. Is there a way to rescue the installation or do I have to start over?
2. In either case, how to install GRUB?

Disclaimers: I am quite young and I have grown up using Mac OS X (and I have never used another OS apart from the inevitable Windowses in school), so my command line skills are very, very limited and the terminology is somewhat alien to me. This whole process is due to a growing interest in Linux.